# Regarding $X \sim N_{0,1}$ and $Y = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} X \\ X \end{array} \right)$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is an exam question given at a statistic and probability course;

If $X \sim N_{0,1}$ and $Y = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
X  \\
X   \end{array} \right)$.

1) find a Borellian $H \subset R^2$ of Lebesgue measure zero s.t. $P(Y \in H) = 1$; deduce from this that $Y$ can't be absolutely continuous.

2) Calculate the characteristic function of Y.

3) Using the characteristic function show that Y has a multi-normal distribution.

**My attempt at a solution**:

1) choose $H = R \times \{ 0 \}$ then $P( Y \in H) = P( \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
X^{-1}(R)  \\
X^{-1}(R)   \end{array} \right)) = 1  $ but the Lebesgue measure of $H \in R^2$ is zero. This means that Y is not absolutely continuous since if it was I could write its distribution as a Lebesgue integral on $R^2$ but the lebesgue integral on a set of measure zero is always zero so I have my contradiction.

2) For point two I am stuck since without a density how can I compute the expected value?

Could anyone help me understand how to proceed? (and if what I have done up until now is right).

Answer (score 3):

Part 1 is incorrect. For your choice of $H$, you have $P(Y \in H) = P(X \in R, X = 0) = 0$. Instead, you should take $H = \{(x, x) \mid x \in \mathbb R\}$.

For part 2, just remember the definition of the characteristic function $\phi(v) = E[\exp(iv^t Y)]$ and use the fact that $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. Part 3 then follows from part 2.

Comment: Thank you Dominik, so $\phi(v) = E[\exp(iv^t Y)] = i E[ \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} k!^{-1} Y^k] = ?$

Comment: That formula is completely wrong in every way.

Comment: I thought this was how the exponential of a vector was defined, should I try using Eulers formula? I apologize it's the first time going through these exercises.

Comment: Could you please explain to me why it's wrong? I am here to learn, I am sorry if I make mistakes.

Comment: Ok I think I understand my error now, so it should be: $\phi(v) = E[\exp(iv^t Y)] =  E[\exp(i (v_1 + v_2) X)] = e^{-1/2 (v_1 + v_2)^2}$ so this means it is multivariate normal with mean $\mu = (0,0)$ and covariance matrix given by the 2 by 2 matrix of ones ?

Comment: That is correct.